# Strip chars in 4 byte

Tags: microcontroller, pic, strip, uart, adc

ok! i want to make one application to show received data on progress bar the microcontroller send adc value from 0 to 1023, but i don't know how to make this i maked serial port terminal:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim RSPort As Array
    Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal [text] As String)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RSPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        LBaud.SelectedIndex = 1

        For i = 0 To UBound(RSPort)
            LPort.Items.Add(RSPort(i))
        Next
        LPort.Text = LPort.Items.Item(0)
        bDisconnect.Enabled = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub bConnect_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles bConnect.Click
        SerialPort1.PortName = LPort.Text
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = LBaud.Text
        SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
        SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
        SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
        SerialPort1.Open()

        bConnect.Enabled = False
        bDisconnect.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub bDisconnect_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles bDisconnect.Click
        SerialPort1.Close()
        bConnect.Enabled = True
        bDisconnect.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
    End Sub
    Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
        If rtbReceived.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            rtbReceived.Text &= [text]
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub LBaud_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LBaud.SelectedIndexChanged
        If SerialPort1.IsOpen = False Then
            SerialPort1.BaudRate = LBaud.Text
        Else
            MsgBox("Only if port is Closed", vbCritical)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub LPort_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LPort.SelectedIndexChanged
        If SerialPort1.IsOpen = False Then
            SerialPort1.PortName = LPort.Text
        Else
            MsgBox("Only if port is Closed", vbCritical)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

to view data witch look same this "1023101509410888085208510828075706520558048704290374" and i want to  display this in progess bar but every number is received 1 by 1 ... sorry for my english i am romanian...

Comment: you need to give us more.  Are you able to get all the data in and just want to parse it in VB?  That's easy.  From the tags you seem to want 32 bit ADC readings.  Post more info or else you will get downvoted into closing.

Comment: Good edit.  This question is now much clearer.  And your english is just fine; don't worry.

Comment: This is actually a VB question, not a PIC or microcontroller question.  You should adjust the tags.

Comment: Post the piece of code of uart_send_data from PIC. If you always send 4 bytes for each sample of ADC will be easy to parse the data.